# Netbeans showing error in design view even though the code is working properly

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, nullpointerexception

I am receiving a null pointer exception error as in the design view but when I run the code it is working perfectly. I can't simply ignore the error because it is making it harder to work in the design view.

How can I fix this or simply remove the error message? I prefer not modifying the code since it is working fine.

Note that I am using lots of customized swing components. Here is a screen capture of the error. Error is not selectable so I can't copy paste it here: 
[image]

[image]
Here is the applyTransparency() method in case it is related

```
  private void applyTransparency() {
    modifiedImg = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(),  BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB); //line 7
}
```

Here is how I load the image:

image is send as an argument in the ImgPanel constructor.

```
  public ImgPanel(BufferedImage image) {
    super();
    this.image = image;
    setOpaque(false);
}
```

I customized the code for the ImgPanel object so that its constructor is called in this manner:

```
 someImgPanel = new gui.customComponents.panels.ImgPanel(GeneralMethods.placeHolderRect(80, 80, Color.RED, "Sleeping", Color.BLUE),0.5f);
```

GeneralMethods.placeHolderRect() method returns a new BufferedImage that is modified to have a rectangle in it.

**Edit**
I've been asked to provide an MCVE. I've decided, time and energy required to fix this problem programatically doesn't worth it so I've simply added `if (image == null) image = new BufferedImage(300, 300, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);`　to get rid of the error. I will delete this line when I'm done working with this form.

Comment: Seems `image` is null. Show how you get that image.

Comment: @alex2410 well the image is shown perfectly when the code is run. I've added it to the question in case it helps. I just want to get rid of the error message.

Comment: Post [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for help.

Comment: Post the actual stack trace, not a _picture_ of it!

Comment: @CatalinaIsland Ok how do I do that? I can't select it. It is not in the output section. It is shown as a background image to the design view and making it harder to see it in the process. I'm updating the image to make it clear.